# Bind with RPZ acts weirdly if a subdomain is used aside a wildcard

Tags: debian, bind, dig

I'm unsure if I found a bug in bind. I've setup a simple dns server on debian 12.

in *named.conf.options*

```
zone "rpz-test" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/rpz-test.zone";
    check-names ignore;
}
```

in *rpz-test.zone*

```
;RPZ
$TTL 604800
@   IN SOA rpz.zone. rpz.zone. (
                2; serial
            604800; refresh
            86400; retry
            2419200; expire
            604800; minimum
)
        IN      NS      localhost.

*.com A 127.0.0.1

sub.domain.com A 127.0.0.1
```

Now... If I use dig to check the configuration once bind9 is started...

This is what happens:

**dig whatever.com @localhost -p 53**
-> replies 127.0.0.1

**dig sub.domain.com @localhost -p 53**
-> replies 127.0.0.1

**dig domain.com @localhost -p 53**
-> breaks the wildcard and is resolved

Practically if there's a subdomain of a domain declared, the main is resolved externally!
Very weird, wasn't the wildcard able to overcome the subsequent declarations?

Probably the problem is in my configuration, not sure if is a bug however the versions I'm using are:

debian 12.2
bind 9.18.19~deb12u1

Comment: Are you sure you've not missed a trailing dot off those definitions? Otherwise `*.com` should actually be `*.com.rpz-test`, etc.

Comment: Oh. And if you're using `rpz-test` as your domain, please don't show examples with `domain.com`; they don't match and we can't tell what your _actual_ tests are

Comment: Furthermore, `domain.com` and `whatever.com` are real registered domains. Please do not use them for examples unless you really are using them in your tests

Comment: @ChrisDavies not sure what you mean about trailing dot, I'm using this as a sort of dns firewall. The real file is full of entries of various domains to block but I discovered that if a wildcard is on and for some reason there's a definition of a subdomain of third level the second level became available and not blocked anymore. I don't want to post the real domains, but could have used google or apple as examples if this suits better. Not sure what kind of domains can be posted as example nowadays they are all registered!

Comment: If you're making things up for the question that you haven't actually tested, I don't think there's going to be any useful way for anyone to help you resolve the issue. DNS is fickle at its best

Comment: @ChrisDavies I tested that configuration, and it produces that result I was talking above. I just simplified the files to the bare minimum in order to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Great. I'll see if I can replicate it tomorrow

Comment: @ChrisDavies ok, let me know if you are able to replicate it, if not I will try to figure out by posting the full bind configuration, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [RFC 1034](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1034.html#section-4.3.3), this is the expected behaviour:

> Wildcard RRs do not apply
> When the query name or a name between the wildcard domain
> and the query name is known to exist.  For example, if a
> wildcard RR has an owner name of "`*.X`", and the zone also
> contains RRs attached to `B.X`, the wildcards would apply to
> queries for name `Z.X` (presuming there is no explicit
> information for `Z.X`), but not to `B.X`, `A.B.X`, or `X`.

If you find this unclear, you are not alone, to the extent that they wrote [RFC 4592](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4592#section-2.2) to clarify the usage of wildcards. To sum it up: as soon as you add an RR entry for `sub.domain.com.`, you are defining two domains `sub.domain.com.` and `domain.com.` to which your wildcard `*.com.` does not apply.

Comment: I see, thank you very much. So there's a special syntax that I can use to make the wildcard go over the specified domains below or the last scenario is remove all the specific domains below when a .com extension is found via an additional script ?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question. If you want to make your `dig domain.com` work, you have to explicitely add an A RR entry for that domain. And you probably want to add a wildcard A entry for `*.domain.com` and `*.sub.domain.com`

Comment: I was asking if there's an alternate syntax for making the configuration not work as RFC 4592 but the way I want, but I guess that weren't so I wrote a script to check for wildcards, and if there were some rewrite the rpz file without any domain ending with that wildcard.